# Hibernate: updating an object in a different Session?

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it bad practice in Hibernate to update an Object in a different Session than it was originally created in? I think the answer is yes, because a Hibernate Session (by default) will cache its Session Objects, and release them when the Session is closed or the Object is evicted. So creating an Object in one Session then updating it in another Session (while the Object is still 'alive' in the first Session) seems like bad practice to me. Can anyone explain why, what are the repercussions? For example, consider this code (which is shortened for clarity):

```
private void updateRequest(Request req){ //Request came from another Hibernate Session
        MyDAO myDB = null;
        myDB = new MyDAO();
            Transaction trans = myDB.getSession().beginTransaction();
            myDB.getSession().update(object);
            trans.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called "Session per operation anti-pattern", here is a [quote from hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-uow) that better explains the issue:

> Do not use the session-per-operation antipattern: **do not open and
>   close a Session for every simple database call in a single thread**. **The
>   same is true for database transactions.** Database calls in an
>   application are made using a planned sequence; they are grouped into
>   atomic units of work. This also means that auto-commit after every
>   single SQL statement is useless in an application as this mode is
>   intended for ad-hoc SQL console work. Hibernate disables, or expects
>   the application server to disable, auto-commit mode immediately.
>   Database transactions are never optional. All communication with a
>   database has to occur inside a transaction. Auto-commit behavior for
>   reading data should be avoided, as many small transactions are
>   unlikely to perform better than one clearly defined unit of work. The
>   latter is also more maintainable and extensible.

Comment: While this is good info, it doesn't answer the question. The question was about if there is any danger in Objects that are created in one Session, but then committed in another Session. This information that you posted is merely saying "don't create a Session for every simple operation, you are being inefficient"

Comment: Sorry for "jumping" into this question..But I always use Session per event (session per operation) and I never encountered any issues or any significant negative "impact" on performance. Can you explain what are the consequences of using Session per operation? Regards.

Comment: @KyleM OK, I now understand better what you want.

Comment: @brano88 I can't explain better than the quote. Maybe you are using session per request? See the link in the answer.

Comment: I saw it..Basically (at least as I understood), they point to use `getCurrentSession`. I recreate Session object upon every new event and close it after transaction is done.

Comment: @KyleM Your exact scenario (`The question was about if there is any danger in Objects that are created in one Session, but then committed in another Session.`) doesn't seem to work. If you don't commit the transaction in the first session, no insert is triggered and then in the second session the update will fail.

Comment: @dcernahoschi I suppose I'll have to create an example and post it because we have this technique in production code and it works. I just don't think it is good practice...